# How to prove Penrose conditions

Tags: matrices

[image]

Can't even figure out how to tackle this problem, just looking for help with the first part.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Just start to substitute $X$ and $Y$, and use orthogonality of $U$ and $V$ (i.e. $U^T=U^{-1}$):
So, e.g. for (a) we get
$$XYX\ =\ U\Sigma V^T \,V\Sigma^\dagger U^T\,U\Sigma V^T\ = \\
=\  U\Sigma\,\Sigma^\dagger\,\Sigma V^T\ =\ U\Sigma V^T$$
which is $X$.